# 12V -> 5V 1A using L7805CV

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, charger

I need to convert 12V (may vary from 11 to 14V - motorbike battery) to 5V 1A (microusb phone charger). I have the [L7805CV positive voltage regulator](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/2143.pdf).

Which capacitors I need to connect at input and output? Any other stuff is needed?

(I need the whole thing to be smallest possible)

Comment: The datasheet recommends 0.33uF at input and 0.1uF at output (page 4 of the datasheet). The capacitors should be ceramic.

Comment: @m.Alin the datasheet is for 10V. For 12 V should be the same? 0.33uF 16V in and 0.1uF 7V out will be ok? Can I connect higher capacity? How much capacity will be too much?

Comment: Why do you say that the datasheet is for 10V?

Comment: @m.Alin p.5 *ELECTRICAL CHARACTERISTICS OF L7805 (refer to the test circuits, TJ = -55 to 150°C, VI = 10V,
IO = 500 mA, CI = 0.33 μF, CO = 0.1 μF unless otherwise specified*

Comment: A heat sink is needed. Power dissipation = V x I = (Vin - Vout) x I = (12-5) x 1 = 7 Watts. You also want a 1A fuse and a 5V1 zener on the output (1 Watt + rated) so that WHEN the regulator fails from vehicle voltage spikes etc the zener will blow the fuse and the cellphone will (possibly) not die.

Answer (score 3):

The data sheets indicate .33uF on the input, and .1uF on the output. Ceramic caps are probably what you want there. Total cost of both on Digikey is around $.60 in singles. If you expect any current surges on the output, you could add a tantalum or electrolytic to the output to handle them.

The caps are a trivial issue compared to the heat sink. For a linear regulator, current in is current out. Input power is 14V * 1A, or 14W. Output power is 5V * 1A, or 5W. The remaining 9W is heat, and 9W in a package that small is a lot of heat. Data sheet says the maximum junction temperature the device can handle is 150C. The data sheet lists the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance is 50C/W. Dump 9W into that and your junction will go 450C above ambient. Far, far above its maximum limit. The semiconductor junction in the device will melt, probably within seconds.

You need a heat sink to reduce the thermal resistance between the junction and the ambient air. Maximum safe thermal resistance between the junction and ambient is (150-40)C/9W = ~12 degrees per watt. Junction-to-case thermal resistance is listed as 5C/W. Case-to-sink thermal resistance for a TO-220 package (not listed in this data sheet) is commonly somewhere around .5C/W. That means your sink-to-ambient thermal resistance can't be higher than 6.5C/W. Looking on Digikey, their cheapest common sink for a TO-220 that gives you any overhead at all is the [7023B](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/7023B-MTG/HS410-ND/1625509) which costs $1.39, twice the cost of your regulator! And now your footprint is larger because of the heat sink.

You can make the entire system much smaller and more efficient by using a switching regulator, and eliminating the need for a heat sink. I recommend the [78SR-5/1.5](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/oki-78sr.pdf), available at [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/OKI-78SR-5-15-W36-C/?qs=uJpRT2lXVNXJP%252bo08dQqJQ==) for under $4 in singles. It costs a couple dollars more than the regulator and heatsink combination, but it greatly reduces the footprint of your circuit, and it's more energy-efficient. You don't have any appreciable heat to worry about, and the current out of your battery is now cut in half. They recommend larger capacitors, ~10uF on both input and output.

I've used these parts in production electronics and had no problems. They're much cheaper than the competing V78xx line of switching regulators, and the footprint is smaller, allowing them to drop into an existing circuit where a 78xx linear would go.

So for an extra $2 or so, you've made the package smaller, and made your battery last over twice as long. Unless you're building a million of these things, that $2 is going to break you, or you don't care at all about battery life, I'd suggest this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen similar charger for Kindle working on 7508 without any radiator. Also, I can use bike frame as a radiator. The general problem is that I'm an electronic lamer and I don't understand basic ideas like what the capacitors are needed for here, and how to calculate the capacity I need to use.

Comment: @takeshin When in doubt, just use the values in the datasheet

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wasting (14-5)*1=9 W (especially if the energy comes from a battery), and having to look for a heat sink, it is better to use a switched regulator like the [V7805-2000](http://products.cui.com/CUI_V7805-2000_Datasheet.pdf?fileID=5286) (you can buy it [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/V7805-2000/102-2175-ND/2352134)) (Vin=7 to 18 V, Vout=5 V, Iout=2 A, pin-compatible replacement, no heat sink required), to save energy and extend the duration of your battery.

**Responses to comments**:

- Yes, it is more expensive, but it is just one piece, one time, and there is a battery involved (with its limited energy implied). I would have no doubts, if I could buy it.
- If you cannot buy it, that's a real problem. In which country are you?
- Regarding Vin_max, its *average* won't exceed 15 V. To avoid the spikes from the alternator from damaging the V7805, a resistor between battery and regulator input will protect the latter one. And, of course, you need capacitors both at the input and at the output. Still, you need to dissipate way much less than with a linear counterpart. Even with a TVS between the resistor and the regulator, this is a better solution than the linear one.
- Even with a 35 V input capable device, you still have the problem with the spikes (which can be of thousands of volts), so you still need either R+C or R+C+TVS.

**Update**: Remiel is right, and his OKI-78SR-5 is a better part option for the same concept.

Comment: minor disadvantage: the part you linked costs aprox. _20 times more_ than an L7805CV

Comment: The max Vin of 18V is also a disadvantage for a motorbike environment. The L7805CV is 35V max.

Comment: @m.Alin And it is hard to buy in my country.

Comment: If using a linear xx7805xx add a series 4 ohm or less 10 Watt air-cooled (ie no heatsink used) resistor from battery to regulator. This will dissipate about 4 Watts of the 7 Watts so you need less heatsinking on the regulator.